# How to specify a declared interface as the type of Map?

Tags: typescript, interface

There was a problem studying the typescript.

How to specify a declared interface as the type of map?

exmaple code)

```js
interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  house: {
    id: number;
    address: string;
    ...,
    ...
  }
  ...,
  ...
}


const userMap = new Map<User>();  // a different motion than expected...
```

Comment: like this `const userMap = new Map<string, User>();` ?

Comment: You are asking for a heterogeneous map, so I'd ask you to reconsider why you would need a map here.

Comment: See the answer to the linked question for more information.  Using that code here gives [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZGgeW).  I have yet to hear a compelling use case for why someone would want to use a `Map` instead of a plain object like `User` or maybe `Partial<User>`, so you should really think about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Map Generics require either 0 or 2 parameters.

If you want the value of the Map to be the User interface, and assuming you want a string as the key, you can do as follows:

```
const userMap = new Map<string, User>();
```

Comment: Thank you for a good idea. 
But what I want is that the key and value of the interface are used as key and value in the map.